# How to convert data format in order to use it for VGG16 deep learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to prepare the training and testing data that will be used in my facial expression recognition model with VGG16. After some research I already knew that the desired data format should be (size, 224, 224, 3). So far I have got:

```
X_train_ (26859, 2304, 3)
y_train (26859,)
X_test (1044, 2304, 3)
y_test (1044,)
```

But when I am trying to further reshape it by

```
X_train.reshape((26859, 224, 224, 3))
```

I got

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 185649408 into shape (26859,224,224,3)
```

I think my y_train and y_test are good, but how should I process X_train and X_test in order in run the training? Am I very far away from the target?

Comment: Well your first problem is that 2304 isn't 224 Squared, so the size of the reshape is wrong

Comment: @Mike is there anything that you would suggest me to do with it? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your data parameters. You clearly have 3 color channels but what are 26869 and 2304? I assume one of these is the number of images and the other is the size of a flattened version of your picture?

Comment: @Mike Yes. I used this set of data with knn before which requires 48 x 48 greyscale. I thought I could just reshape on the base of those.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem you should first convert your data to a tensor with shape `(26859, 48, 48, 3)` using `reshape` function as follows:

```
X_train.reshape((26859, 48, 48, 3))
```

After that, since the VGG16 Net accepts tensors with shape `(size, 224, 224, 3)`, you are supposed to use zero paddings to insert extra zeros to the borders of the training and testing images in order to increase the widths and heights of them.

One of the available functions to zero-pad an input tensor is `tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D`. It is an extra layer that applies zero paddings to the input tensors.

For more information about the ZeroPadding2D layer, refer to its documentation [tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D API DOC](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ZeroPadding2D).

Answer (score 0):

```
IMAGE_SIZE = [512, 512] # any image size 192, 224, 331, 512
# 512 works for TPU as GPU has memory limit
# Decode Function
def decode_image(image_data):
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_data, channels=3)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0  # convert image to floats in [0, 1] range
    image = tf.reshape(image, [*IMAGE_SIZE, 3]) # size needed for TRAINING
    return image

# Now train with ant pretrained models
pretrained_model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False ,input_shape=[*IMAGE_SIZE, 3])
pretrained_model.trainable = False # False = transfer learning, True = fine-tuning
```